# How is a dissertation plan written and how to learn writing it

Tags: research-process, thesis, teaching, writing, research-undergraduate

I am a Law student with an Economics Background (School of Economics, Department of Economics, Economic Theory and Policy)

I have a dissertation to write on Spatial and Urban planning. I have an Interdisciplinary Subject (Law and Economics).

Today is day 1 and I was told to write a plan (I was told just these couple of words).
I know how to solve differential equations because the teacher spent a lot of their time actually teaching it substantially. They didn't just hand out the problems and say solve them.

Isn't there a general methodology (recipe, algorithm) for actually writing the dissertation plan; what is it?

They spent much more time explaining references and citations (a procedural triviality because in the end we can learn the way just from glancing at the textbooks almost every textbook has the same way to make references and citations).

Comment: Did you ask your instructor? What did they say?

Comment: @BryanKrause "No one knows how to write a dissertation from the start. Everyone learns by writting. Practice makes Perfect." it seems to be pretty much like handing out a Problem Set and waiting until the students "learn" figure out how to solve the equations on their own. After a lot of insisting on not knowing what to do/ what to write I got the advisor to at least help me figure out if said equation is an ODE or a PDE.

Comment: Please don't consider references and citations a triviality.  There are two reasons.  First, there arr several "right" ways to do these, and your institution has almost certainly picked one of them.  Second, an error could end your academic career.

Comment: @BobBrown I could end up in jail for Plagiarism. But the "suggested" or "preferred" text books all (almost) follow the same way to make citations.

Comment: Surely your institution or department *prescribes* something like the APA or MLA form.  If not, *pick one* and include it in your plan.  (In the U.S. you won't go to jail for plagiarism, but you might get dismissed from your program.)

Comment: What is your research question?

Comment: @padovapadova What do you mean research question? My dissertation is on Planning Law (economic analysis of expropriation and similar concepts). Law and Economics. The "question" basically is do these concepts make sense is the a better (more efficient economically) alternative without risking undercompensation or undue and unwarranted government actions (actions with a social deficit not even Kaldor-Hicks improving)

Answer (score 2):

Does your institution have something called a *Dissertation Guide*?  If this is an American university, I'd be surprised if they didn't.  Such a document won't tell you *anything* about the research content of a dissertation, but it ought to tell you how to organize yours.  In other words, it should tell you the deliverables you will have to produce for a successful dissertation.  Although Stack Exchange discourages links in answers, here is an example of what I'm talking about: https://computing.nova.edu/doctoral/documents/dissertation_guide.pdf

Once you know the deliverables you have to produce in a finished product, you can make that plan you were asked for.  It might start out something like:

- Dissertation idea paper: Months 1-2
- Research on XXX (as described in idea paper): Months 3-4
- Dissertation proposal: Month 5
- ...

You should be able to produce a *start* on something like that pretty quickly, but note that the bullet list above is specific to one institution. You will also need more detail than some one-line bullets.  You can then ask your advisor whether that's on the right track.  If so, you're golden.  If not, one can hope you'd get guidance on what's wrong.

Let me say it again... the example is from a specific institution.  You should find the similar document for your own institution and not try to use what's in the link.

Comment: > Stack Exchange discourages links in answers ... really? SE discourages link-only answers but not links in answers afaik